# How can I make the checkbox checkbox enabled by default?

Tags: wordpress

How can I make the checkbox checkbox enabled by default? here is the code

```
<label class="checkbox woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox" data-automation-id="woo-commerce-subscription-opt-in">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin" id="mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin" value="1"> I have read and agree to the site terms and conditions *<span class="optional">(necessarily)</span></label>
```

Solution found thanks to @Eduhud Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin').prop('checked', true);
        }, 500);
        var checkout_is_updated = false;
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
            $( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function(){
                $('#mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin').prop('checked', true);
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
(function($) {
    jQuery('#mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin').prop('checked', true);
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: I tried like this: but it didn't work for me! maybe did something wrong?

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin').prop('checked', true);
});
</script>

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: yes/ https://disk.yandex.ru/i/Qc91mEPHgMc6kQ

Comment: where you're adding the Jquery codes, I've just updated my codes again, add it inside functions.php file and let me know.

Comment: <script>
(function($) {
    jQuery('#mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin').prop('checked', true);
})(jQuery);
</script>

I tried adding this code header.php and footer.php

Answer (score 0):

Just add checked

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin" id="mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin" value="1" checked>
```

Comment: But how to add this hook to functions.php? because every update of the plugin erases the change

Answer (score 0):

**If you have access to the html structure**, the answer of @Ali jezzni should work, just add `checked` to the `<input>` field.

In your case:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin" id="mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin" value="1" checked>
```

**If you do not have access to the html structure**, a good option is using **jQuery** to change the element once the page is loaded, as @Rakesh Sharma explains by targeting the element and using the `.prop('checked', true)` function of jQuery.

In your case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin').prop('checked', true);
        }, 500);
        var checkout_is_updated = false;
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
            $( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function(){
                $('#mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin').prop('checked', true);
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I wrote your js code! The tick is put down but then removed disappears!

Comment: And when choosing a payment method, it updates and removes the check

Comment: Do you have an live url so I can try?

Comment: In addition, I tried this code which solved the problem:
<script>
(function() {
setTimeout(() =>    jQuery('#mailpoet_woocommerce_checkout_optin').prop('checked', true),
 1000)
})()
</script>

but, I get a check when the payment method changes

Comment: Tested the last edited code from my answer. It should work.

Comment: thank you very much @Eduhud . Everything worked!

Comment: You're welcome @Абушаев-Руслан. Please mark my answer as the solution (tick) and thumb up (arrow up)!